# Server Core box keeps losing secure channel to domain, netdom can't reset?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have one WS2012 box that repeatedly loses its secure channel to the domain. If I try to run netdom verify/reset, I get the "no logon servers were available" error message. If you look in the event log of the problem server, you do see lot of event 5719 entries:

This computer was not ablt to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain  due to the following:

%There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.

Netdom reset fails (no logon servers). Forcibly removing the box from the domain, followed by an AD exorcism and a re-join fixes it for a short while, but it eventually comes back. I've tried updating the NIC drivers to no avail.

I'm stumped. Can someone give me pointers for what I should be looking for, here?

Comment: Your computer can't contact a domain controller.  So, your troubleshooting steps are 1) figure out why it can't communicate with a domain controller and 2) correct the problem.

Comment: Yes, I realize it's having difficulty contacting a DC, hence trying verify, reset, etc. I just don't know what diagnostic measures to take to determine WHY it can't contact it. If it couldn't contact it at all, I shouldn't be able to join the domain. If it were some thing that happened after I joined the domain, then why is it that the box can re-join?